# Composition of functions proofs

Tags: calculus, function-and-relation-composition

I would like some help with proving or disproving the next statements:

> - If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are defined on the same domain $D$ than $f\circ g$ and $g\circ f$ are also defined on D.

I think this is not true but only if I can look on part of the domain. for example if $D$ is {$x\in \mathbb R| x\ne0$} and $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ $g(x)=\sin x$ than $f\circ g$ is not defined for every $n\pi$ for every natural n. but can it be false if you look at two functions with exactly the same domain?

> - If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are defined for every $\mathbb R$ than $f\circ g$ and $g\circ f$ are also defined for every $\mathbb R$

I think this is true since for every 
$x$ I will input $f(x)$ is defined and for every $x$ I will input in $g(x)$ it will also be defined so also $f\circ g$ will be defined.

> - If $f\circ g =g\circ f$ than $f(x) = g(x)$

I think this is false. for example: $f(x) = -x$ and $g(x)=x^3$

> - If $f\circ f=g\circ g$ than $f(x)=g(x)$

I think this is false. for example $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ and $g(x)=\frac{2}{x}$

My main problem is I'm not sure how to approach proving the true statements.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: "*If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are defined on the same domain $D$ then $f\circ g$ and $g\circ f$ are also defined on $D$*"  What is important to functions is not only the domain but **also the codomain**.  Take for example $f$ the function from words to natural numbers counting the number of letters in the word and $g$ the function from words to natural numbers counting the number of $a$'s in the word.  E.g. $f(\text{apple})=5$ and $g(\text{apple})=1$.  Now... what is $(f\circ g)(\text{apple})$?  Similar problems can occur with $\Bbb R$ as the domain where the codomain is not a subset of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Note that all four statements are false. (JMoravits and AJ Stas have both implied it but they haven't explicitly said it.)

Comment: @TannerSwett why is the second one false? of g(x) gives any real value than $f\circ g$ gets a real value therefore it's true

Comment: can you give a counter-example?

Comment: Counter example:  $g(x) = x^2 + 7$.  $f(x) = $"babar, the elephant".  $f(1) =$ "babar, the elephant".  $f(\pi)=$"babar, the elephant".  $g(f(x) ) = g($"babar the elephant"$)$ is undefined.  For a less silly example.  Let $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R\times \mathbb R$ via $f(x) = (-x, x^2)$ let $g(x) = x^2 + 7$.  Then $f(2) = (-2, 4)$ and $g(f(2)) = g((-2,4))$ which isn't defined.  g is defined to have only a real number input; not an ordered pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f,g:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$, then since $f(x),g(x)\in\Bbb R$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$, we have that $f(g(x))$ and $g(f(x))$ are defined for all $x\in\Bbb R$.

This is, in general, not true if $f$ and $g$ do not have the same codomain.

Comment: I now understand how to prove it. thank you!

Comment: Wait, why would that not be true if the have different codomains.  The codomains are still subsets of R and thus subsets of the domains of the other.  For any $x \in \mathbb R$ then $f(x) \in \mathbb R$ is defined.  And as for every $y \in \mathbb R$ then $g(y) \in \mathbb R$ is defined. So $g(f(x))$ is defined.  Surely the statement is true?

Comment: @fleablood You're obviously correct, but OP never specified these were real-valued functions.

Comment: The OP didn't but ... you did????  I'm a bit confused as *you* are stating that the are real valued functions????

Comment: I showed how one could prove the claim true if they are real-valued (which is what I assumed OP had in mind considering the calculus tag). I added a disclaimer about how this is not necessarily the case if the functions aren't real-valued.

Comment: Okay.  That is absolutely true.  It wasn't clear you were countering the statement as stated in the OP.  I read it as you were quoting the OP (albeit adding the real valued condition), and then saying the statement (with the real value condition) was not always true.  I simply misread your post.